# libspotify and glibc versions

Tags: c, linux, spotify, glibc

I would like to develop a Linux application that uses libspotify (latest and greatest libspotify-12.1.51-Linux-armv6). The problem I'm facing is that my target system uses an older version (2.3.6) of glibc compared to the one used by current libspotify. How can I proceed without having to wait for a matching update for my target system? Is there any chance Spotify can provide libspotify variants for older glibc versions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that libspotify does require glibc 2.7.0, and that's not something we can easily change.  If it was easy we already would have :-).

So your best bet would be to find an update for your target system.

Regards //Johan

Comment: The manufacturer of my target system is not releasing updates very often and when they do they lag _a_lot_ with respect to latest glibc version. So I guess at the time they've reached 2.7.0, you guys will be way ahead again! Would it instead be possible to use an old version of libspotify (that uses glibc 2.3.6)?